# Custom YAML types for gatsby-transformer-remark

Tags: yaml, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby, and using the `gatsby-transformer-remark` plugin to load data into my page using graphQL. And I want to perform a custom string manipulations on some data stored in my Markdown frontmatter.

I thought using a custom YAML type would be a good way to do this because this can be done at compile time, and there's no need to do it at runtime. (The plugin run at compile time to generate data, I believe?) For example, I could define a custom type called `max` which returns the maximum number in a given array, and use it directly in the markdown file as follows:

```
---
foo: !max
  - 2
  - 4
  - 5
---
```

Is it possible to define a custom YAML type for the frontmatter parsed by `gatsby-transformer-remark`? Or, is there a different and better way to handle this situation?

I can see that the gatsby plugin uses `grey-matter` for parsing the front matter, which uses `js-yaml` for parsing YAML. I know it's possible to define custom YAML type in `js-yaml`. But, I can't seem to find how to pass options to `js-yaml`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to pass options to `js-yaml`, you'd have to define a custom yaml engine, then pass it to `gray-matter` via `gatsby-transformer-remark`'s options.

Define a custom yaml engine:

```
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const schema = require('./custom-schema');

const customYamlEngine = (str) => yaml.safeLoad(str, { schema });
module.exports = customYamlEngine
```

And then pass it into `gatsby-transformer-remark`

```
const yaml = require('./custom-yaml');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
+       engines: { yaml },
        plugins: [
          ...
        ],
      },
    },
  ]
}
```